# Ignore a literal file graphql string deprecated fields warning with eslint-disable

Tags: typescript, graphql, eslint

I was trying to ignore a literal file graphql string deprecated fields warning with eslint-disable with a comment but it's complaining that `//` is not recognize. Tried `#`, `"""` but none of the mwork within the graphql string in typescript. Is there a good way to ignore the check for a specific line/query than ignoring the check for the whole file?

```
const query = gql`
    {
        whatever {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            field
        }
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that

```
/* eslint-disable graphql/no-deprecated-fields */
const query = gql`
    {
        whatever {
            field
        }
    }
`
/* eslint-disable graphql/no-deprecated-fields */
```

works better than eslint-disable the whole file